# Translation of "What did you find interesting ..."

Tags: prépositions, adjectifs, attributs

"What did you find interesting in this film?"

Should the translation be

> Qu'est-ce que vous avez trouvé original dans ce film ?

or

> Qu'est-ce que vous avez trouvé **d**'original dans ce film ?

The first one might make sense since we say "Je trouve original que ...." (not "Je trouve **d**'original que ..."), while the second one might make sense since we say "Je ne trouve rien **d**'original" (not "Je ne trouve rien original"). So I'm not sure which translation is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This translation is correct :

> Qu'est-ce que vous avez trouvé d'original dans ce film ?

Do not forget the question mark.

And "Je trouve original que " is more about something in it's globality than a specific thing, if you want to ask about the movie in it's globality by instance you should rather say :

> Ce film était-il original ?

Answer (score 0):

1-ce film est ou n'est pas original.

2-L'idée contenue dans 1 est présupposée dans 'Qu'est-ce que vous avez trouvé d'original dans ce film?' C'est pour indiquer cette pré-existence mentale que 'de' apparaît obligatoirement.

Exprimé de manière différente:

1-Le choix de parler de l'originalité de ce film arrive mentalement en premier.

2-Mais seulement dans la deuxième partie de l'énoncé. C'est à dire après 'Qu'est-ce que tu as trouvé'. Conçu en premier mais exprimé en second: c'est ce qui rend obligatoire l'apparition de 'de'. 'de' code cela.

Comment: Parler de classification n'est-il pas une explication plus simple dans ce cas ? Expliquer phénomène plus général de l'apparition de *de* me semble un peu ambitieux dans le cadre de cette question.